# File not found VM UWP media element

Tags: azure, media, uwp, filenotfoundexception

I am using a media element to load and play a file in my app (universal windows platform).

My visual studio is broken so i am working on it on my azure virtual machine, it works fine on my system, but when I try it on virtual machine without changing anything, it gives me an exception of file not found, I used the break point, it actually gets the file properly, but gives exception when I try to load that file into media element.

Why is it giving this problem only on virtual machine?

Comment: Have you tried a 'repair' both on Visual Studio 2015 *and* the Windows 10 SDK in Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: yes i have, problem is not with visual studio, problem is something else

Comment: When you create a `MediaElement` in code (not XAML), what exception do you see? also, can you post some code and what type of files you're trying to play?